# Use of offset in virtual addresses

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

As far as my understanding goes, the CPU always generates a virtual address that is made-up of 2 parts- the page number and the page offset. The page number is used for indexing the page table (the corresponding mapping gives the starting address of the frame in the RAM). Now, please consider the following questions. Consider that the word size of the machine is 4 bytes, and the page size is equal to the frame size = 4096 bytes.

1. Supposing that the page number is 4 and the offset is 3. Then Page 4 in the logical memory maps to frame 8 in the virtual memory. This means that the starting address of the frame is 8.
2. Now, each frame will contain 4096/4= 1024 words. Does the offset imply for a word inside the frame, since the machine will always fetch a word at a time? What I mean is that does it mean the 3rd word in frame 8?
3. Is the particular word given to the CPU, or the entire frame? If former, then why does everyone talk about transfer in terms of frames and pages rather than words?
4. Suppose a page fault occurs. What this means is that the particular page in not in memory. Does it mean that the physical address mapped contains some other page? Does the mapping even exist in such a case when the invalid bit is 1.

Can someone clear-up things for me? One moment I seem to get it, and the very next, I get into a maze.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point of paging is that it deals with "chunks" of memory.
It is a map, a function, that translates virtual addresses into physical addresses but not on an address-by-address base. Rather, a "chunk" of *continuous* virtual addresses is translated *together* into another *continuous* "chunk" of, now physical, addresses.
You can think of it as a "translation" or "shuffle" of "chunks" of memory.

[image: Shuffing of "chunks" of memory]

The correct term for "chunk" is *page*.
If try to do a sample mapping you can see that each page contains a set of addresses that all have a peculiarity: their lower bits *don't change* when passing from virtual to physical. The upper bits instead are arbitrary.
This dichotomy of the address value defines the *Offset* and *Page/Frame number*.
The offset is the part of the address value that don't undergo any translation. 
In a page of 4KiB there are 4096 addresses, each one with its offset, so the offset has size *log*<sub>2</sub>(4096) = *log*<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>12</sup>) = 12 * *log*<sub>2</sub>(2) = 12 bits.
In short the page size determines the offset size.

It is *necessary* to break the memory into pages and not words or byte, or in another view it is necessary to group the addresses to translate into pages.
Without pages, the metadata used for the translation, in jargon the page tables of various level, would occupy more memory that the one that under translation!

Offsets are relative to their page/frame thanks to the way their are defined: the offset 1024 (in hex 400h) in the frame 8 means the address 8000h + 400h = 8400h; if the page is mapped to the frame 12 the offset 1024 is still 1024 bytes after the beginning of the frame, 0c000h + 400h = 0c400h.

Being an address, an offset usually denotes a byte, event in architecture where bytes are not addressable. However this is not a standard convention, to know if an offset denotes a word or a byte (e.g. if offset 10 of frame 0 is the byte 40  or the byte 10) check the architecture manual. The first sections are usually dedicated to establishing a terminology to use throughout the book.

Paging happens before the CPU accesses the memory, you can think of it as an high level process. The unit that accesses the memory/bus is mostly unaware of it, as such the CPU read the data that the instruction is telling it to read (a word, a byte, and so on).
People talk about moving a page because a page is the *smallest unit that can be characterized*.
You can mark a page as non present, but not a word. You can make a page read-only but not a word.
If you need to map, say 16 bytes, you still need to map a whole page since 16 bytes are not characterizable. So we might as well read a whole page.

When a page-fault occurs it means that the page accessed is, at any level in the page-tables, non present.
This may mean a wide range of things, from the fact that the Present bit has been simply toggled (with the page still there), to the fact that the page has been saved to disk and zero-ed in memory.
Since the mapping function is *total*, meaning that every value is a valid value, the CPU need a way to know when a value is not valid.
The Present bit does this: tell the CPU that a translation must not be performed and that an exception must be raised instead.
The OS use this exception to be notified of when a page is needed, it doesn't need to reassign the mapping to another page or zero the memory.
When people say that a page is *removed* they mean that it is removed from the mapping, all modern OSes also zero-d the page to prevent leaking of information to other processes though.

So if a physical frame is not mapped it doesn't mean that another page in another process is mapping it, it simply mean that that range of addresses cannot be accessed.
As said above there are a lot of reasons for an OS to do this, including protection.

Answer (score 1):

You have things a bit backwards. The operating system defines a logical address space for each process. The logic address space is divided into units of memory called PAGES.

The operating system logically maps the pages of the address to either physical page frames or secondary storage If the operating system maps pages to secondary storage then is using virtual memory.

In ye olde days all systems that did logical memory translation always did virtual memory mappings to secondary storage. That is why the terms virtual memory translation and logical memory translation are often conflated. These days it is becoming increasingly common to have logical translation without virtual memory.

All address accesses through a process are to logical addresses. The processor translates the logical address to page frames. If logical page exists but is mapped to secondary storage, accessing that page triggers a page fault. The operating system must handle the fault, remap the logical/virtual page to a physical page frame; load the data from secondary storage to the page frame; and restart the instructions.

> 1. Supposing that the page number is 4 and the offset is 3. Then Page 4 in the logical memory maps to frame 8 in the virtual memory. This means that the starting address of the frame is 8.

This make no sense. A logical page is virtual when it is mapped to secondary storage. If the page number is 4 the 4th logical page can:

a) have no mapping at all (access violation)

b) map to a physical page frame

c) map to a secondary storage (virtual memory)

> 2. Now, each frame will contain 4096/4= 1024 words. Does the offset imply for a word inside the frame, since the machine will always fetch a word at a time? What I mean is that does it mean the 3rd word in frame 8?

In nearly all (if not all) current processors there are no memory words; only bytes. The system bus fetches memory and the "word size" of the bus can be (and often is) different from the "word size" of the processor.

> 3. Is the particular word given to the CPU, or the entire frame? If former, then why does everyone talk about transfer in terms of frames and pages rather than words?

The process sees transfers in sizes related to the instruction being executed. The operand size can be larger or smaller than the machine word. The bus transfers data to memory and that size is frequently different from the word size of the machine.

> Suppose a page fault occurs. What this means is that the particular page in not in memory. Does it mean that the physical address mapped contains some other page? Does the mapping even exist in such a case when the invalid bit is 1.

I gave the three possibilities for logical page mappings above. How those are indicated are system specific. Some systems use 2 bits to indicate a, b, or c. Others use a single bit to indicate (b) and require the operating system to determine whether it's (a) or (c).

Whether or not a page fault is triggered depended upon the state of the page table.

Generally a page fault means that the page frame is not in memory. However, it is often possible for the physical page frame to be in memory but not mapped in the page table (a soft page fault). (This occurs when the operating system has unmapped page frames to free some up but has not reallocated them.) In this case, the operating system simply needs to update the page table to point to the page frame and restart the instruction (no need to load from secondary storage).